# How to handle INTERVALs in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, dml

I didn't get how  to insert an `INTERVAL` inside a database with SQL.

Here's an example of a table with an "interval" column. Here I used `INTERVAL DAY(4)` supposing I won't ever input more than 9999 days (i.e. more than 27 years).

```
CREATE TABLE Satellite (
  SatelliteName     VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  MissionTime       INTERVAL DAY(4),
  StartingDate      DATE                    NOT NULL
);
```

If I want to insert a satellite inside the table, knowing the mission started the 2009-07-10 and ended the 2013-06-17 what should I do?

```
INSERT INTO Satellite (SatelliteName, MissionTime, StartingDate)
VALUES ('Hershel', ????? , '2009-07-10');
```

Note: I'm using **PostgreSQL**

Comment: What is your RDBMs? Tag your question accordingly to get appropriated attention.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for your suggestion! I'm using postgresql (just added it to the tags)

Comment: Just use the word interval and the time span like `insert ..... values... ( ..., INTERVAL '689 days', ... );`

Comment: @JorgeCampos so why using `INTERVAL`s? Can't I do the same with an `INTEGER`?

Comment: With an Interval type the calculations with date columns will be easier and transparent whether you do a calculation in an interval with any time span like seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc. With just an integer you will have to know which it is to do a proper conversion and only then get the right result.

Comment: Oooh and this is my thinking. There is nothing wrong with using an integer. Read this related post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60470/use-of-integer-instead-of-interval-of-one-type

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an interval?  Just use the number of days, and store it as an int.

You can do the arithmetic as:

```
select startingdate + missiontime * interval '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make_interval(days := '2013-06-17'::date - '2009-07-10'::date)
```

or

```
'2013-06-17'::timestamp - '2009-07-10'::timestamp
```